# How do I write a script that will change the size of text and app when opening a program?

Tags: windows, batch-file, resolution

I have a Windows 7 laptop with the size of text and apps set to small. However, one program I use needs this setting to be set on medium. I'm sick of changing this setting every time I have to use the program.

How do I use a batch file to change the size and text of this program to medium without impacting other programs and keep the resolution at 1280x960?

I have no previous experience in writing batch files.

Comment: Please take a look at the site [tour] and [ask] before updating your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If the program is a batch file or its cmd.exe, you can just create a shortcut to that program, go into shortcut properties, go into the Layout tab and set the window size by changing Width to the width you want the window to be and the Height to the height you want to window to be. For the text go into the Font tab and set the text size to an option already there or input a custom one by clicking in the box that tells you the size selected and type in your own. Then press enter. This will close the properties. You must do this or it will go to the nearest option to your custom size. Now simply run the shortcut instead of running said program and it should have custom size and text.